# Polynomial solution of an equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

We consider the IVP $$y
'' −2xy' + 4y = 0, y(0) = −3, y'
(0) = 0$$
(the unknown is denoted by y(x)). Prove that the solution of this IVP is a
polynomial function. Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: Try to find a polynomial that satisfies this then prove it is the unique solution (linear ODE).

Comment: but how to find this polynomial?

Comment: By inserting a good guess and solving the equation. Try first with a monomial $y(x)=x^n$ and see where that leads you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, one can always try a polynomial of degree $2$, a quadratic:

$y = ax^2 + bx + c; \tag 1$

$c = y(0) = -3; \tag 2$

$b = y'(0) = 0; \tag 3$

then

$y = ax^2 - 3; \tag 4$

$y' = 2ax; \tag 5$

$y'' = 2a; \tag 6$

thus,

$y'' - 2xy' + 4y = 2a - 4ax^2 + 4ax^2 - 12 = 2a - 12 = 0, \tag 7$

and so

$a = 6, \tag 8$

whence

$y = 6x^2 - 3. \tag 9$

***Check:***

$y' = 12x, \tag{10}$

$y'' = 12, \tag{11}$

$12 - 2x(12x) + 4(6x^2 - 3) = 0✓. \tag{12}$

Note that

$y(0) = -3, \; y'(0) = 0. \tag{13}$